# How can I allow user to upload own PDF and have it displayed?

Tags: html, pdf

I have a website for school where every teacher is going to have a page. Each teacher's page will have a spot for them to upload a PDF. I want this to then show in a viewer on the page so students see the Viewer when they access it.

How would I code into the website allowing the user to upload a PDF and not have it replaced until somebody else uploads a PDF?

so far I have the code to upload a document.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fup.cgi">
 File to upload: <input type="file" name="upfile"><br/>
Notes about the file: <input type="text" name="note"><br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Press"> to upload the file!
</form>
```

How can I get it to go into a viewer below? and that it saves until replaced.

Answer (score 0):

1 - First thing you are not able to upload file to server but your form action is claiming to use CGI, 
2 - Second i cant really get what you want but the following code can upload files to server its in PHP and otherthing are you using SQL or what Database are you using it seems you also need database

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
if(!is_dir("uploads")){
  $uploadDir = mkdir("uploads");
}
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "docx", "doc");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

     }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Do you want to display pdf thumb, icon, or read the pdf

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried it yet. I will be trying it after school today or on a prep. I would like to display a whole PDF. Teachers will be typing up a document where they will convert it into a PDF from word or Pages. I would then like them to locate their page on my website. They will then see a "choose file". When they press upload, it will show beneath and stay there until it is replaced at another time. This way students can access the site and see the PDF.